# Appending text into TextArea

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I'm trying to create a `TextArea`,

```
@FXML 
private TextArea ta;
```

and what I'm trying to get :

```
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    ta.setText("    Field " + i + "\n");
}
```

but it only show the last line : `Field 5`.
Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ta.setText("")` before the loop, then in the loop, `ta.setText(ta.getText() + "    Field "+i+"\n");`

Comment: You can also use `textArea.appendText(" Field "+ i +"\n");` in the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `setText( "...")`, you replace the text which is already there. So either construct your String before setting it, or append it.
Try this:

```
String text="";
for (int i=1;i<=5;i++) {
    text = text + "    Field "+i+"\n";
}
ta.setText(text);
```

Note: You'll probably get better performance and it's considered "good practice" to use a "StringBuilder" instead of a String to build String like this. But this should help you understand what's the problem, without making it overly complicated.

Comment: If I understand things correctly, the compiler would convert the code you showed into the equivalent with a `StringBuilder` anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The method `.setText()` puts only one value into the field. If a value exists, the old one will be replaced. Try:

```
private StringBuilder fieldContent = new StringBuilder(""); 
for (int i=1;i<=5;i++)
 {
   //Concatinate each loop 
   fieldContent.append("    Field "+i+"\n");
 }
 ta.setText(fieldContent.toString());
```

That is one way to achive it.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is by using the `appendText` method

```
for (int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
    ta.appendText("    Field " + i + "\n");
}
```